# Identify pages which refreshes automatically in my site

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site which uses wordpress. For some reason, some of my pages keep refreshing continuously. I am not able to replicate the issue continuously. However, in random I have seen some pages keep refreshing automatically. When I retry the same pages after few mins, it is working fine. My users also experiencing the same problem. When they report me the issue with a url and if I check that page it is working fine. So, I am sure the issue is there but unable to replicate the problem or troubleshoot the issue.

This is not a browser or system issue. The issue occurs with registered and unregistered users.

So, I need your help on this to troubleshoot this problem. Is there anyway to find out whether the page is keep refreshing by adding some code in wordpress theme php files like writing some sort of logs, etc.? So that I can try to troubleshoot the problem.

The same theme with plugins works fine in another site with other hosting provider. I have also checked with my hosting provider. They replied back and said they are not able to find any issues on their side and cannot help further, as the issue occurs in random.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: where is the webpage, what page usually does it? Could be .htaccess http://www.blackhatworld.com/blackhat-seo/cloaking-content-generators/46957-double-meta-refresh-htaccess-method.html, http://frontdeskapp.com/goodwebmastering/how-to-view-htaccess-files-on-your-server/

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your site may have been hacked. Check the page source (`View Source` or `Ctrl + u`) for `<script>` tags that you don't recognize. If you are unsure, try disabling all of your plugins and use the default theme. If the issue persists, then it is most likely an issue with your site being hacked, and you should reinstall WordPress from scratch, and do fresh installs of all plugins and themes. If you are using a custom theme, upload a version that you know was working. Also, *be sure to change passwords for your dashboard and hosting account*.

If disabling a plugin or using the default theme makes the issue go away, then it's a bug with that particular theme/plugin. In this case, report the bug to the appropriate party (person/company responsible for the particular plugin/theme that's causing the issue).

### How to Debug

Try to find a way that you can consistently test for the problem. For example, if you can refresh 20 times, and it happens twice every time, then you have your test to use. It sounds like it won't be as simple as this, but that's the basic idea... find the minimum number of times it takes to come across the issue on a regular basis, and test for it 3 times for each plugin you disable (and when you turn the main theme back on).